# Pygame - How do I check if my rect has already been clicked?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, rectangles

What I'm trying to do is if a rect has been clicked, it is selected and text will display, but if its clicked again, then it is de-seleced and the text goes away.

list_of_rect is a list of coordinates (x, y, width, height) representing the position and size of the rect.

render_display just shows the screen with text.

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
    x, y = event.pos
    for i in range(len(list_of_rect)):
        j = list_of_rect[i]
        if j[0][0] <= x <= (j[0][0] + j[0][2]) and j[0][1] <= y <= \
                (j[0][1] + j[0][3]):
                render_display(screen, text)
```

**EDIT**: One idea I was thinking was to keep track of the rectangle that has been clicked on. But I'm not sure how to implement this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try having a list, like this:

```
rects_clicked = []
```

Then, in your event code:

```
if j not in rects_clicked:
    #undisplay text
    rects_clicked.append(j)
else:
    #display text
    rects_clicked.remove(j)
```

Comment: I used a variable called selected_rect instead, and used your idea. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: This would only work if @Theo is storing the rectangles in a list. He (sorry if wrong pronoun) has already stated that the only info being stored is list_of_rect, which contains coordinates, not rectangle objects

Comment: @PMARINA assuming that `list_of_rect` stores its data like `[[x, y, width, height], [x2, y2, width2, height2],...[xn, yn, widthn, heightn]]` the rects_clicked does not need to keep track of the rectangle objects but instead checks if the sublist is in `rects_clicked`. So `rects_clicked` might look like `[[x, y, width, height], [x3, y3, width3, height3]]` which is fine for the OP's requirements

Comment: @PMARINA essentially each group of coordinates can be treated as an object

Comment: @rassar Shouldn't it be if j not in rects_clicked: rects_clicked.append(j) else remove j? Just a suggestion for op, object oriented programming would make it a lot cleaner, as if anything but primitives are stored in the lists, it could cause issues.

Comment: @PMARINA that's true but Theo isn't using objects and it probably won't matter that much. I could add a basic class if you really want me to.

Comment: @rassar just a suggestion for op

Answer (score 1):

I would use a 2d list containing Booleans. When the rectangle is clicked, I would say `list[xCoordOfRectangle][yCoordOfRectangle] = !list[xCoordOfRectangle][yCoordOfRectangle]`. Then, in the drawing method, I would say:

```
for i in list:
    for j in i: 
        if(j): 
            #information drawing function goes here
        else:
            #Solid/Empty Rectangle drawing function goes here
```

Note that you would need to initialize `list` to have false for every rectangle. Also note that if the rectangles are not arranged in a rectangular fashion, you would need to use numbers in the following way: 1 is assigned, true; 2 is assigned, false; 3 is unassigned (sort of like null). Either that, or you could just have a one-dimensional list to store the Booleans and then keep track of which element in the list is which element.